# Proportionally Resizing images in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to resize widescreen/highscreen images proportionally so they fit a square-thumbnail-div and don't become distorted.

I tried it this way in my stylesheet:

```
.PicsNav img {
max-width: 74;
height: auto;
max-height:74;
width:auto;}
```

Works fine in both Chrome and Safari but Firefox doesn't handle it correctly. The Pics won't be resized - instead they are shown in full size one above the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add a unit when setting a width and height. I'm guessing you want 74 pixels?

```
.PicsNav img {
    max-width: 74px;
    height: auto;
    max-height:74px;
    width:auto;
}
```